# Hibernate deleting non-orphaned child

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data and Hibernate, `CascadeType.ALL`, and `orphanRemoval = true`.

The issue is, when moving a child entity from parentX to parentY, Hibernate deletes the child entity from the database altogether if parentY is persisted before parentX.  After which, the child still exists in parentY in memory.  And if it is removed, and parentY saved, an `EntityNotFoundException` is thrown.

I have an SSCE demonstrating this and can post it if necessary, but it seems like a simple issue.

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestParent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3572015072906463953L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TestParent_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TestParent_GENERATOR", initialValue = 1, sequenceName = "TestParent_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TestParent_Id")
    private Set<TestChild> testChildren = new HashSet<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TestParent() {
    }

    public TestParent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void addChild(TestChild child) {
        this.testChildren.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(TestChild child) {
        this.testChildren.remove(child);
    }

    public TestChild findChild(String childsName) {
        for (TestChild testChild : this.testChildren) {
            if (testChild.getName().equals(childsName)) {
                return testChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestChild implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1594688339088954284L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TestChild_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TestChild_GENERATOR", initialValue = 1, sequenceName = "TestChild_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TestChild() {
    }

    public TestChild(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provie code of your entities.

Comment: Does `TestChild` have an association back to `TestParent` (perhaps via a filed)? The posted code does not show any such relationship.

Comment: @Eruza, can you check the sample app linked in my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

The entity mappings are incomplete from a Hibernate perspective, which is why you may be getting unexpected results. The biggest culprit is `orphanRemoval = true`, which has been used without using `mappedBy = ...`. Although the JPA specification does not require `mappedBy = ...` to be specified with `orphanRemoval = true`, Hibernate has trouble determining if an entity on the `many` side of a one-to-many association is really orphan if `mappedBy = ...` is not specified.

The following mappings will correct the behaviour:

```
class TestParent {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "testParent")
  private Set<TestChild> testChildren = new HashSet<TestChild>();
}

class TestChild {
  @JoinColumn(name = "TestParent_Id")
  @ManyToOne
  private TestParent testParent;
}
```

Note that `@JoinColumn(name = "TestParent_Id")` needs to be moved to the `@ManyToOne` side.

You also need to be very careful about the change of parent. If the child is left in the `children` collection of the previous parent, the change will not take effect.

---

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/37704926) that demonstrates a working JPA configuration. The project contains a unit test that simulates the following situation:

1. A `Child` instance `c` is created.
2. A `Parent` instance `a` is created.
3. The `Child` instance `c` is added/assigned to the `Parent` instance `a`.
4. `a` is saved. This cascades down to `c`, which also gets saved.
5. Another `Parent` instance `b` is created.
6. The `Child` instance `c` is added/assigned to the `Parent` instance `b`.
7. `b` is saved. This cascades down to `c`, which also gets saved.

In this scenario we expect the following SQL queries to get executed:

```
INSERT INTO parent (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO child (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO parent (...) VALUES (...);
UPDATE child SET ...;
```

If you run the unit test as `mvn clean test` you will see the SQL queries being executed as expected.